# How can i get another string from select query?

Tags: java, mysql, string, jsp

I want to get string from column no. 4 from my database to check user privileges.

Can I use `rs.getString(index)` to get data from column no.4?
I want to check user´s privileges...so if the column data is equal 4, the page will be redirected to AdminControlPanel.jsp
BUT, this code doesn´t work :(

```
String user=request.getParameter("login");
String pass=request.getParameter("password");
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/android","root","root");  
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users where login='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'");
           String p = rs.getString(4);                   
           int count=0;
           while(rs.next()){
           count++;
          }
      if(count>0 && p == "4"){
             // out.println(rs);
                           response.sendRedirect("AdminControlPanel.jsp");
                      }
          else{
               out.println("aaa");
               response.sendRedirect("#");
           }
        }
                 catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: How this code doesn't work? Any errors? Not the expected results? please explain.

Comment: don't select '*', select only colums you actually use. Also use prepared statements and sanify inputs.

Comment: code seems fine what and yes you can directly take the value of any column , what is the error you are facing ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are comparing two String objects rather than checking the values in the String.

just change the code to **p.equals("4")** and try.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
while (rs.next()) {
   String val = rs.getString(4);
   ....
```

Note that iterating through a `ResultSet` iterates through the *rows*. For each row, the column indexing starts from '1'.

However it's safer to get by column name, since your SQL query doesn't specify neither the columns nor the order in which they're returned:

```
String val = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
```

I see from the below that you need an integer. Check out the doc for [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for more info, but:

```
int val = rs.getInt("COLUMN_NAME");
```

As an aside, I don't see you closing your `ResultSet`/`Statement`/`Connection` in the above. If you're not, then you'll need to!

Comment: I change it to my column name, but the effect is similar. It doesn´t redirect me to AdminControlPanel.jsp
What should i use, if the column type is int?

Answer (score 0):

```
String p = rs.getString(4);   // This should be inside your while                  
int count=0;
while(rs.next()){
    count++;
}
```

- You should move your first line inside your `while` loop. You can't
  fetch the columns of a row, until you move your cursor to that row
  using `res.next()`.
- Also, since your database should ideally have only `one` record for a
  combination of `username` and `password`. So, you can better use an
  `if` instead of `while`.
- And you don't really need a `count` variable there.

**So, your code should be: -**

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users where login='"+user+"' " +
                              "and password='"+pass+"'");
if (rs.next()) {
    String p = rs.getString(4);  // Note that using Column name is a better idea

    // or rs.getInt(4) if the column type is `int`

    if(p.equals("4")) {   // Use equals method to compare string content
         response.sendRedirect("AdminControlPanel.jsp");

    } else{
         out.println("aaa");
         response.sendRedirect("#");
    }
}
```

Also, note that you should compare your string using `equals` method. `if (p == "4")` will give you false result. `==` operator does not compare the content of the string, rather the content of the reference used in comparison.